# zip a directory that name start with `-`

Tags: zip

How can I zip a directory like `-foo`?
`$ zip "-foo" "-foo"` shows only help page.

I think `-foo` is recognized as a options, but I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general way for doing things like this is to prefix the file name with `./`.

```
zip foo.zip ./-foo
```

This technique works most other utilities which accept a file name as an argument.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
zip foo.zip -- -foo
```

Simply put `--` before the filename(s).

Answer (score 6):

Try using `--`

For example:

```
zip foo.zip -- -folder
```